# How can I sort files by date that are in document directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITableView` that's being populated with a list of csv files located in the `NSDocumentDirectory`.
I'm able to load and sort the files alphabetically but would like to sort them by creation date instead.

How do I filter the files by creation date?
Do I have to manipulate the files to include creation date when they're persisted, or do they already have that as an attribute?

This is how I access the files:

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableArray*   fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

//--- Listing file by name sort
NSLog(@"\n File list %@",fileList);

//---- Sorting files by extension

NSMutableArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil].mutableCopy;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF EndsWith '.csv'"];
filePathsArray =  [filePathsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].mutableCopy;
NSLog(@"\n\n Sorted files by extension %@",filePathsArray);
```

Comment: Your question is muddy and vague. It sounds like you don't want to "sort files", but want to present a sorted list of files in a table view. Sort how? Alphabetically? By date? What do you mean "I need to add the date attribute when  I create the files"? Where are these files coming from? What is the code that you posted? it appears to be building an arbitrary list of paths from a property dirList, which I assume contains an array? Where does this code live? Is it extracted from a cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: This is truly an indecipherable question. You need to spend some serious time editing it to provide a clear picture of the problem you're trying to solve, as well as providing some context, both for the files you're trying to present, and for the code that you posted without explanation.

Comment: Duncan,i have to improve my english that's true, i'm not a native english you have show more respect for people that doesn't speak your native language and beginners if you are too good programming and smart is very easy to know what i'm asking. If i mention date is clear that i want to sort files by date  the files are in document directory as mentioned in the first line, sounds like you are anger and unhappy.

Comment: No, I could not figure out your question. It gets frustrating reading really poorly explained questions. The problem with your question is not just the language problem. Your question is incomplete and not at all clear. Please go back and edit your question to show the full method for the code you posted. Also please state that you want to sort your list of files by date (created date? Modified date?)

Comment: Okay, sorry you are right wasn't clear  i modified  not sure if is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far from clear, but at a guess you are wishing to sort file names based on their creation dates.

You have a file path so can create an `NSURL` for it - see Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc). Once you have created the `NSURL` instance you can use it to obtain information about the file - read the *Accessing Resource Values* section in the documentation. If you are interested in the creation date you can get that with the `NSURLCreationDateKey` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlresourcekey?language=objc)).

Obtain the creation dates for all your files then sort the file names according to those dates. If you get stuck ask a new question showing what you've wriiten, where it goes wrong, etc. and someone will undoubtedly help - linking back to this question is also a good idea.

HTH

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what i need.